# warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I'm trying to write a program as an assignment. The user should input 7 floats which will then be stored in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  float data[32];
  printf("Instert 7 values, separated by spaces: ");
  scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f", data);

  return 0;
}
```

And I keep getting the error

```
warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f", data);
```

I tried to look for a solution online but I couldn't figure it out, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to specify each `data` item individually: `scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f", &data[0], &data[1], &data[2] ... );` Also, check the return of `scanf` to make sure it matched as many as you are expecting. Have a look at the [`scanf` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: Ohhhh I see, thank you. Is this the only way to assign the values? Any other more efficient way?

Comment: @FoxyIT use a loop.

Comment: there are certainly other ways to input data to a program. Depends on what you mean by "efficiently". Sounds like `scanf` here is just fine for your assignment requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f", data);
```

should be like this

```
scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f", &data[0], &data[1], &data[2], &data[3], &data[4], &data[5], &data[6]);
```

The scanf function requires, for each *%-something* on the initial string, a pointer to a variable where you'll be storing the input value.

You could alternatively write like this:

```
scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f", data, data+1, data+2, data+3, data+4, data+5, data+6);
```

Your array's base memory address/pointer is *data*. When you sum it with an *i* where *i* is a positive integer, you get the pointer to the *ith* position in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    scanf("%f", &data[i]);
```

With error detection:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// ...

int num_values_read = 0;
for (; num_values_read < 7 && scanf("%f", &data[num_values_read]) == 1;
     ++num_values_read);

if (num_values_read != 7) {
    fputs("Input error :(\n\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that would work, my goal is to let the user write the 7 floats all at once separated by spaces. Wouldn't they need to hit return in your case?

Comment: @FoxyIT No need for hitting return.

Comment: This method has no way of detecting input failure part-way through; the subsequent code might go on to access uninitialized values. Whereas the original form could check the return value to know how many valid entries have been written.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you what is wrong it is just unfortunate that your variable name matches the error messages words.
`scanf` wants a variable for every `%` there is in the format string. That means in yout example it expects 7 variables but only gets 1.